# Why catch error does not work when I have 401 error on refresh token request?

Tags: angular, error-handling, angular-http-interceptors, refresh-token

If any other request has 401 error refresh token executed and then I have 3 cases

1. If I send a **valid** refresh token works as expected
2. If I send a **not valid** refresh token I have 401 (from backend) and catchError does not work
3. If I send the wrong request (example: incorrect URL) I get 500 catchError work.

**angular service**

```
  refreshToken(refreshToken: string): Observable<any> {
    return <Observable<any>>(
      this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/auth/refresh-token', {refreshToken})
    );
  }
```

**angular interseptor**

```
intercept(request: HttpRequest<unknown>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<unknown>> {
    let authReq = request;
    const token = this.storageService.getToken();
    if (token != null) {
      authReq = this.addTokenHeader(request, token);
    }
    return next.handle(authReq).pipe(catchError(error => {
      if (error instanceof HttpErrorResponse && error.status === 401) {
        return this.handle401Error(authReq, next);
      }
      return throwError(error);
    }));
  }


  private handle401Error(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler) {
    if (!this.isRefreshing) {
      this.isRefreshing = true;
      this.refreshTokenSubject.next(null);
      const token = this.storageService.getRefreshToken();
      if (token) {
        return this.authService.refreshToken(token).pipe(
          switchMap((token: any) => {
            this.isRefreshing = false;
            this.storageService.setToken(token.accessToken);
            this.storageService.setRefreshToken(token.refreshToken);
            this.refreshTokenSubject.next(token.accessToken);

            return next.handle(this.addTokenHeader(request, token.accessToken));
          }),
          catchError((err) => {
            this.isRefreshing = false;
            console.log('catchError');
            this.storageService.clearStorage();
            return throwError(err);
          })
        );
      }
    }
    return this.refreshTokenSubject.pipe(
      filter(token => token !== null),
      take(1),
      switchMap((token) => next.handle(this.addTokenHeader(request, token)))
    );
  }
```

Please tell me what am I doing wrong and how to do it in a right way

Answer (score 0):

Add below code inside `else` statement:

```
return this.refreshTokenSubject.pipe(
  filter(token => token !== null),
  take(1),
  switchMap((token) => next.handle(this.addTokenHeader(request, token)))
);
```

Comment: `handle401Error` is this function getting called ? did u try using logger ?

Comment: yes, it's called and it works correctly if I have 401 for my request.
but if I have 401 on refresh token request after failed previous request catch error doesn't work in handle401Error

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem here with the very **same implementation**, perhaps the only little difference was the request route "https://localhost:5001/api/v1/auth/refreshToken".

To make it work I simply changed the response **401 to 404 NotFound** on backend, this way nothing goes wrong with angular interseptor.

Unfortunately after many tries I didnt find the cause of this problem, so I end up with this **workaround**.